# How do I prevent my static assets from being processed by my routes with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask, the python web framework. In my application I have a route like `@route('/<book>/<chapter>/<verse>')`. My static assets (css and js) are being processed by this route, so the development server will return a template instead of the css or js file.

Is there any way to keep this route but exclude routes matching my static assets?

It seems that I'm missing something obvious here, so my apologies in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to handle static assets with Flask is to create a directory named `static`, put your assets in it, and then use the `'static'` endpoint name.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files

---

Alternatively, if you're using a separate webserver to host your Flask app (via WSGI or similar), configure that webserver to override the paths for static assets and never pass them to the app in the first place.

Comment: All of my assets are in the `static` directory and I am using `url_for` in my templates. For example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">`. Does it matter that my assets are in subdirectories within `static`?

Comment: Shouldn't, no. You might want to consider adding at least one non-variable path to your routes, even if it's something short like `/b/<book>/...`